# Do not count same element in Python while reading csv

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in reading csv file.

Here is my code:

```
mycsv = pd.read_csv('1.csv', index_col=None, skiprows=0)
for k in range(0, 11):
   link = mycsv.columns[k]
   print(link)
```

Here is my CSV file:

[image]

You can see that there are same elements in some columns.

While printing the output is adding number from the 2nd duplicate element:

Here is the output:

```
TRUE
TRUE.1 
TRUE.2 
TRUE.3 
TRUE.4 
TRUE.5 
FALSE  
FALSE.1
TRUE.6 
TRUE.7 
TRUE.8
```

I do not want the number after the element:

I want this one:

```
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE  
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
```

Is there anyone who can help me about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv
mycsv = pd.read_csv('1.csv', encoding="utf-8", index_col=None, skiprows=0)
for col in mycsv.columns:
    link = col[:col.index('.')] if '.' in col else col
    print(link)
```

> FALSE 
> TRUE
> TRUE
> FALSE
> TRUE
> TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Since, data is in a single line, you can just use:

```
line = list(mycsv.iloc[0])
# iterating through the line
for i in line:
    print(i)
```

Comment: It still prints out the numbers though. In addition, you do not need to use ```iloc```, if you want to get column names, you can use ```mycsv.columns```.